# Faster loading of R Markdown html document

Tags: r, r-markdown, lazy-loading, ggplotly, lazy-initialization

Dear StackOverflow members,

I am creating big html documents using R Markdown. These documents contain 200 till 300 charts generated using ggplotly. The creation/knitting of these files works well. Though, these files can be 40-50 MB in size and are very slow to load in a web browser. It can take multiple minutes to open the html document in a web browser.

I tried speeding up the loading of these html documents by using the lazyrmd package, but this didn't work. Also, the lazyrmd package seems discontinued.

**Are there alternative ways to speed up the loading of big html documents with many ggplotly charts that were generated using R Markdown?**

Thank you!

Comment: In my experience, `ggplotly` is quite heavy. If you need interactive plots, you could consider using [dygraphs](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/) which is more limited but much lighter and more efficient to load in Rmarkdown.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Does there exist a function similar to ggplotly() to automatically transform a ggplot object to a dygraphs object?

Comment: No, I don't think so. This kind of limitation probably makes dygraph lighter & efficient.